# Display data using sqlite3 in C application

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm developing C Program that will help me to display the browser history.
Whenever I run any sql Command in sqlite it displays all history in file. 
This is what Sql command is(history file that contains history of chrome)!

> sqlite3 History "select datetime(last_visit_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch'),url from  urls order by last_visit_time desc" > history_export.txt

It gives me a good result for example

> 2017-06-28 10:20:20 | stackoverflow.com
>   2017-06-28 8:20:20 google.com 2017-06-28 
>   07.10:20 | facebook.com
>
> ### ETC

And then I want to have the same result but with C Application.
This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *err_msg = 0;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("c:/Users/XXXXXX/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/History", &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n",
        sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }
   //the same command works fine in sqlite3
    char *sql = "select datetime(last_visit_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch'),url from  urls order by last_visit_time desc";

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &err_msg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
//declaration of callback function i think that the problem is here
int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv,
                    char **azColName) {

    NotUsed = 0;
    FILE *fp ;
    fp=fopen("C:/sqlite/historyc.txt","w");

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

        fprintf(fp,"%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");

    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It displays me 2 or 3 lines of an old visit (20/03/2017..)
But I want to have the same result that I get with the sql command. 
Probably the problem is due to the Callback function.

Comment: If you program in C, why add the C++ tag? C and C++ are different languages. And what does this question have to do with the Google Chrome web-browser? Please don't add irrelevant (language or other) tags to your questions.

Comment: The callback is run for _every_ row returned by the query.  Every time it is run it creates your historyc.txt file from scratch and writes a row to it.  Hence you end up with only one entry and it's the last one returned by the query.  Answer #31146713 might be helpful to you.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't solve my Problem .Sql command will retrieve two columns Datetime and URL . Normally if callback runs each row then i will get the final row but it isn't true it display me a random row ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `fopen(...,"w")` to `fopen(...,"a+")` fixes the problem for me.  This is because your code currently wipes the file every time it opens it, which is every row (overwriting the previous row).  `a+` will append to the existing file instead of wiping it, so you will get all the rows printed in the file.  You will need to manually delete historyc.txt each time you run the programme though, otherwise it will keep growing.

Of course, `"a+"` just a dirty hack in this context and not a very efficient one.  Another *slightly* more efficient hack is to make `*fp` global and then open the file before your `exec` statement (and remove `*fp` and `open` from the callback function).  Still dirty but at least this means the file is only opened once.

Code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int callback(void*, int, char**, char**);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *err_msg = 0;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("your_db_file", &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n",
        sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;
    }
    char *sql = "select datetime(last_visit_time/1000000-11644473600,"
                "'unixepoch') as visit_time,url from  urls order by "
                "last_visit_time desc";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &err_msg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 0;
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0; 
}

int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv,
                    char **azColName) {
    NotUsed = 0;
    FILE *fp ;
    // Very dirty but it works for me
    fp=fopen("/tmp/historyc.txt","a+");
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        fprintf(fp,"%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    return 0;
}
```